# How to deal with JavaScript when trying to fetch web page in C#.NET/WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, javascript, wpf, forwarding

The .NET `WebClient` class is nice and all, but it doesn't parse the JavaScript in the page.

What I mean is, sometimes a page is forwarded to a different page via JavaScript, or sometimes DOM elements get added to the page via JavaScript with an onload event.  I need to deal with both of these situations.

What can I do to deal with this?  I'm using WPF if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

To do this in managed code would *essentially* mean writing your own browser. I expect that to do what you want the simplest approach would be to drop a `WebBrowser` control into the page (essentially re-hosting IE) and use that. There are other hostable controls, of course - but that is the simplest for Windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [WebBrowser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.aspx) control. This approach is not as "lightweight" as using the `WebClient`, but short of writing your own javascript parser this is probably the easiest solution.